# How put HashMap in AngularJs function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How get Hashmap from rest and put it in $result AngularJs.

I tried:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('EntitesController', function ($scope, $stateParams, Entites) {
    $scope.all = {};

    $scope.load = function (id) {
                Entites.get({id: id}, function (result) {
                    $scope.all = result;
                });
            };

            $scope.load($stateParams.id); 
});
```

But in all - nothing. I`m sure thar rest give Hasmap but i have no idea how put this hashmap in result.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like:

```
webPortalApp.controller(
'AboutController', 
function($scope, $log, $http) {


    $log.log('Creating request...'); 

    var req = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'rest/app/information/'
    };

    $log.log('Executing request...');

    $http(req).success(
        function(data) {
            $scope.properties = data;
        }
    ).error(
        function(data) {
            $scope.properties = 'unknown';
        }
    );

    $log.log('Executed request.');

});
```

and:

```
<div><table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <tbody>

        <tr ng-repeat="(k,v) in properties">
            <td>{{ k }}</td>
            <td>{{ v }}</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table></div>
```